# MySQL Server not running

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry for my bad English.
After upgrading MySQL up to 5.6.17 version it's not working. I'm using Windows 7 as my server's operating system.
Here is the my.ini and error log:

```
[mysqld]
basedir=C:\_server\_release\_backend\Mysql\
datadir=C:\_server\_release\_backend\Mysql\data\
port =3306
back_log = 50
flush_time=0
max_connections = 30
max_connect_errors = 10
open_files_limit=4110
key_buffer_size = 25M
read_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
join_buffer_size = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 1M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 2M
max_allowed_packet = 2M
max_heap_table_size = 25M
max_sort_length = 20
max_tmp_tables = 25
table_open_cache = 400
table_definition_cache = 400
tmp_table_size = 25M
wait_timeout=60
interactive_timeout=30
ft_min_word_len=4
thread_cache_size = 4
thread_concurrency = 4
connect_timeout = 5
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=25M
query_cache_limit = 256K
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 256M
myisam_repair_threads = 1
myisam-recover-options=backup,force
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
lower_case_table_names = 2
#innodb_force_recovery=6
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_file_format = barracuda
innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet =16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer =20M
sort_buffer_size =20M
read_buffer =2M
write_buffer =2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer =20M
sort_buffer_size =20M
read_buffer =2M
write_buffer =2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout



2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.15 started; log sequence number 1600339
2014-04-03 23:21:51 7788 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I can't disable InnoDB data storage, because I want to use it in future. Currently no tables using this storage. I hope you can help me. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no data in InnoDB, try deleting the InnoDB log files `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`. The error log entry indicates that these somehow cause the problem.

Comment: I tried to do it over 100 times - no result.